# How to change solr field type after data is already indexed

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene

I had indexed a lot of data to `solr`. 
One field named id is indexed as `multivalued` and `string` type `(id:["123"])`.

Now I want to change the field to int i.e `(id:123)`.

Can I change the field type and how to effects the already existing data?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can change the field type and also the `multivalued` as false by modifying the field from the `schema.xml` or `managed-schema.`

Once you modify the field type of field, you need to `reindex` the data.

I would suggest to create another collection using modified/different `configset`. This modified `configset` will have all the required changes to your schema.xml.

Once you upload this `configSet`, create a new collection and start indexing the data in your new collection.

Once indexing is complete. You can create an alias to the new collection and provide the alias name same as earlier collection, in order to avoid the downtime.

After the alias creation whatever searches will happen will be executed on the new collection.

Comment: I have huge amount of data for example in thousands(100K) How can i reindex it

Comment: I would suggest to create another collection using modified/different configset...(This configset will have all the required chnages to your schema.xml) ...start indexing the data in your new collection...once indexing is complete ...you can create an alias to the new collection and provide the alias name same as earlier collection...in order to avoid the downtime...